# Git commit failing always due to GPG error

Tags: git, gnupg

I am seeing below error every time I commit in git.

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

But, if I edit the expiration date of the key using `gpg2 --edit-key B2C093EFB44F5C8A078439288C205B1C93FFBAF7` I am able to commit successfully. The problem is I need to update the expiry date always before doing a commit. Is there a way we can avoid changing the expiry date and permanently make not complain about gpg error?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Zsh.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sign a commit with an expired key, if you wish to not need to extend a key's expiration date, you can make a key that doesn't expire, or edit your current one. By following [this article](https://www.g-loaded.eu/2010/11/01/change-expiration-date-gpg-key/),try running:

- `gpg2 --edit-key B2C093EFB44F5C8A078439288C205B1C93FFBAF7`
- Select the correct subkey with `key #` where # is the index from
  `list` starting from 0
- Run `expire` and select 0 (never expire)
- Repeat for other subkeys
- `save`
- If needed, update the public key on registered keyservers

Comment: I updated the expiry as "Never expire", it worked at that moment, but if we try committing after some time again I need to edit the key using gpg.

Comment: I chose never expire (option 0 in the edit window)